# AngularJS - Form with Select element to get Id from another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a two tables "Category" and "Publication" with a One to Many relationship.

**Category:** id, name, description

**Publication:** id, title, content, category_id

And I need to get the category id through a select element and put it in the category_id field.

Publication form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="publication.title" placeholder="Title" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="publication.content" placeholder="Content" />
  <!-- Here is my problem because I can list all categories but I can't get the category id and put it in the category_id field -->
  <div ng-init="categories()">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
        <option value="">-- Select category --</option>
    </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is my controller to get all categories:

```
$scope.categories = function() {
    $http(
            {
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/prodemo/category'
            }).success(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.categories = data;
            }).error(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
};
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to use the ID of the category to filter the publication select, correct?

Comment: @reptilicus Yes, I need to create a publication with an specific category to then filter publications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like below with a hidden field you can easily do that

```
    <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="publication.title" placeholder="Title" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="publication.content" placeholder="Content" />
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="publication.category_id = category.id" />

      <div ng-init="categories()">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
            <option value="">-- Select category --</option>
        </select>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks dude but I have the following error in console: **Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'publication.category_id = category.id' is non-assignable**.

Comment: I think you are using an older version of angular js.this should be work on angualarjs 1.4.1 '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>'

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="getPubs()" ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="">-- Select category --</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_pub" ng-options="pub.name for pub in publications">
    <option value="">-- Select Pub --</option>
</select>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.getPubs = function () {
   //or whatever the URL for filtering publications by catagory_id
   $http.get('/prodemo/publications/' +  $scope.category.id)
     .then(function (resp) { $scope.publications = resp})
}
```

Comment: Looks good but the first step is assign a category id (to the new publication) in the publication form.This is why I'm trying get the id through a select element and put it in the category_id field. This is what I can't do now. Give me a hand with this little nightmare.

Comment: I thought they had to select one first? If not, can just pre-select one like $scope.category = $scope.categories[0]